# HTML5 Canvas Drag and Drop with snap-to-grid and revert support

Tags: html, canvas, drag-and-drop

I have a html5 canvas with 10x10 grid. 
User can drag and drop tetrix-like object inside that grid.
Objects must be snapped to the grid (on drag) and if it is dropped on other objects, it must revert to the original position.
(like JqueryUI draggable)

I know that EaselJS, KineticJS support drag& drop. 
But I cannot find any documentation or tutorial to implement snap and revert support.
Is there any existing solution or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: The GoJS library has snap-to-grid features and an undo manager. It is not free, however. Here's one sample that uses both features: http://gojs.net/latest/samples/planogram.html

Comment: The GoJS sample looks great (if my project is bigger, maybe I will consider buying a license...). I have implemented my simpler solution with some aabb and Math.round logic. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: just to be clear, by snap to grid you mean that position must always be multiply of grid size (eg if grid size is 100x100 objects can only move in steps of 100 pixels), or do you mean when an object is near a grid line it will snap to it based on configurable threshold (but if not close to grid will move freely)?

Comment: @hope_is_grim could you please share by posting your "simpler solution" as an answer to this question? it would help us those who come here! btw your question has 5 upvotes and 3 boomarks!  thanks.